# Is it worth to enable statistics on Mysql

Tags: mysql, database, performance, phpmyadmin, statistics

There is a link named "Enable Statistics" under "Database" tab on PhpMyAdmin.

1. In which cases Enabling statistics can improve or decrease server performances (CPU/RAM/IO/Execution time)
2. In which cases Enabling statistics can provide false results

Thank you.

Comment: That seems to be something that PhpMyAdmin does, not something that MySQL is doing.

Answer (score 1):

It's not quite clear what exactly you're asking here, but I'll give it a shot.

The statistics that can be shown there require extra server processing time to calculate. I just did two quick tests, one server with 400 tables and 4 million rows stored; the other has 47GB of data across 300 tables total. Both loaded almost as quickly as the page normally loads, the delay is only fractions of seconds in both cases.

This setting is not persistent, it only loads the additional statistics during the active display and the database tab returns to the standard display the next time it is viewed.

Selecting to enable these statistics gives additional information for each database and totals for the entire database server.

Number of tables, number of rows, amount of data, amount of indexes (indices?), total data stored, and overhead are the additional columns shown.

> In which cases Enabling statistics can improve or decrease server performances

Gathering additional statistics would never improve server performance. It would decrease if you have a massive amount of data or, I'm guessing here, such load that the tables couldn't be locked long enough to compute the statistics.

> In which cases Enabling statistics can provide false results

I don't think that's something that's warned about here or likely to happen; there can be inconsistencies with the way data usage is calculated especially when there is overhead involved or a database has many deleted records, since the size MySQL uses on disk won't decrease automatically even after rows are deleted. This can lead to MySQL showing a small database size but still using a larger amount of disk space, but that isn't going to be shows as false results through phpMyAdmin here. Other than that, I'm not sure what you're asking about as far as false results would be concerned and perhaps you'd like to clarify if I haven't answered well enough.

Comment: I come from Microsoft SqlServer's World and below is the idea that it is in my mind about statistics (maybe out of scop)

- statistics are important because they help the Query Optimizer
- statistics hold information about columns the Query Optimizer uses to generate query plans
- Query Optimizer create on how to execute a query and find data the efficient way (it is why I'm talking about improving performance in my first question)

Is it the same on Mysql?

Source: [link](https://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/how-to-optimize-sql-server-query-performance-statistics-joins-and-index-tuning)

Comment: Indexes and indices are both good nowadays :)